# Convert ArrayBuffer of wav file to Blob

Tags: javascript, html, blob, arraybuffer

I'm trying to fetch from the server an **audio wav file**, and play it in the client with the element.

```
<audio id="recording" src="..." />`
```

I got the data as ArrayBuffer, and im trying to convert it to blob so I can change the src of the element

This is the code:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080/", requestOptions)
    .then( (response) => {
        return response.arrayBuffer()
    }).then( (data) => {
        let a = new Blob([data], {type : 'audio/wav'});
        document.getElementById("recording").src = a;
    })
    .catch(error => console.error( error));
```

But there is an error:

```
GET chrome-extension://goohbjdkcejkkochpdellmjkkdpfngph/[object%20Blob] net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

It seams I didn't create the Blob properly

How can I create the blob and pass it to the `<audio ... />` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) an actual URL from your blob. And don't forget to [revoke](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL) it afterward to free the resources.

```js
let blob = new Blob([data], {type : 'audio/wav'});
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
document.getElementById("recording").src = url;
URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```